# How can I remove the reviews section from the product details page? Magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, theme, luma-theme, magento2.2.7

I am using standard Luma theme installed with Magento 2.2.7. I would like to remove the "Reviews" panel completely and also the links below the Add to Cart button.

Where can I find the template files to comment these areas out? My theme appears to be inside /vendor/magento/.......

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below override file in your custom theme after change it

> app/design/frontend/{vendore}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

add **body** tag in

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am new to Magento 2. Can I just edit the theme that is already there that was installed? Do I need to actually create a new theme to do this?

Comment: you can not created new theme then you can change vendor luma theme